# SSL TLS 1.2 Channel creation VB.net HTTPS WebRequest

Tags: vb.net, ssl, webrequest

I have a legacy Visual Studio 2010 vb.net application that I need to update the SSL TLS channeling to support TLS 1.2. I have tried a couple of different options (see commented code for attempts) and all lead me to the same error, "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." What am I missing?

```
Public Shared Function processCCRequest(ByVal strRequest As String) As String
    'declare the web request object and set its path to the PayTrace API

    Dim ThisRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://beta.paytrace.com/api/default.pay")
    'configure web request object attributes
    ThisRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ThisRequest.Method = "POST"

    'encode the request
    Dim Encoder As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    Dim BytesToSend As Byte() = Encoder.GetBytes(strRequest)

    'declare the text stream and send the request to PayTrace's API
    Dim StreamToSend As Stream = ThisRequest.GetRequestStream
    StreamToSend.Write(BytesToSend, 0, BytesToSend.Length)
    StreamToSend.Close()

    ''ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    ''allows for validation of SSL conversations
    ''ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf)
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
     ''| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    ''var(response = WebRequest.Create("https://www.howsmyssl.com/").GetResponse())
    ''var(body = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd())


    'Catch the response from the webrequest object
    Dim TheirResponse As HttpWebResponse = ThisRequest.GetResponse

    Dim sr As New StreamReader(TheirResponse.GetResponseStream)
    Dim strResponse As String = sr.ReadToEnd

    'Out put the string to a message box - application should parse the request instead
    ' MsgBox(strResponse)

    sr.Close()
    Return strResponse
End Function
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: I think that TLS 1.2 support was added in .NET 4.5, so you need that installed and then use the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)` work-around for 4.0 code.

Comment: Yes and in my answer I went a few steps further based upon this information to complete my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was completely successful after downloading and installing the .net 4.6 Targeting Pack from Microsoft. This added the full .net upgrade that includes TLS 1.2 support and added .Net 4.6 as a publishing option. Once I upgraded and published, the code above worked with the security protocol set to TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 4):

If You used .net 3.5, use this script

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
```